# Separate business-domains in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

Good morning - i have 2 domain mapped by business requirements:

- Client
- Trainer

---

I created different models for each type - there are:

```
public class Client
{
    [Key]
    public string ClientId { get; set; }

    public byte[] Avatar { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; } ...another properties

}
```

}

---

```
public class Trainer
{
    [Key]
    public string TrainerId { get; set; }

    public byte[] Avatar { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; } ...another properties
}
```

---

and add to DBSets

```
public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
public DbSet<Trainer> Trainers { get; set; }
```

---

The problems:

1. Classes inherit many values ​​- should there be an abstract user class?
2. How can I refer to the elements of the Trainer and Client class equally - e.g. during authentication - I would not like to write two methods this way:
3. Identity the both domain by one userID

   ```
    public interface IUserService
    {
         Client Authenticate(string email, string password);
         Trainer Authenticate(string email, string password);
    }
   ```

---

I spent a lot of time on Identity.netCore and Application User - but nothing got me to understand how to solve this

Comment: We cannot answer this without understanding what are the exact business differences between a `Trainer` and a `Client`. Do they do different things? Do they have different permissions? Are them different tables just to keep them separated? You have to provide this and more information to allow us to give you an informed answer

Comment: Yes - they will have another behaviour and properties in the future. Also the relationship between them is important - Trainer and Client are in many-to-many relationship

Comment: The important issue to they should have common logic - authenticate, get by id, create etc.

Comment: OK, but that important information needs to go in the question, which you should [edit]. Also, authentication should be agnostic of Client/Trainer, and for that to work you'll need those to have a `UserId` (or similar) property and authenticate using a generic `User` (or similar) class

Comment: I used abstract class - User, Trainer and Client inherits from this - all three models have UserId - Trainer additional have TrainerId and Client additional have ClientId.

Comment: What You think about this?